# Update two rows with same query in vb-mysql

Tags: mysql

im using this code to update a column on mysql but i want add other column, how i can do it?

Here is my code:

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE EmployeeInfo Set nivel= nivel + 1 WHERE user_name = ('" & My.Settings.user_name & "') AND password = ('" & My.Settings.user_password & "')"
```

Y want anything like this, but that give me a error:

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE EmployeeInfo Set nivel,puntos= nivel + 1, puntos -200 WHERE user_name = ('" & My.Settings.user_name & "') AND password = ('" & My.Settings.user_password & "')"
```

Comment: Please show us the error itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update statement is wrong , I think you are looking at something like

```
UPDATE EmployeeInfo 
Set nivel = nivel + 1,
puntos= puntos -200
where ...
```

Comment: You can write that in one line.